# Why is *SGI + Nginx/HTTP considered the best practice for deploying web applications?

Tags: django, deployment, httpserver

My friend recently asked me the following question: given that Django already has `runserver`, why didn't wasn't it extended to be a production-ready customer-facing HTTP server? What people do instead is set up an `uwsgi` server that speaks WSGI and exposes something that Nginx forwards traffic to by reverse proxying...

Based on what I know, many other languages use this pattern: there is a "simple" HTTP server meant for development, as well as an interface for *GI (ASGI/WSGI/FCGI/CGI) that web server is supposed to reverse proxy to. What is the main reason those web servers don't grow production-ready and instead assume presence of another web server?

Here are some of my theories, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something more significant:

- History: dynamic websites date back to perl/PHP, both worked as a "dumb" CGI backend that was basically a filter that processed HTTP request (stdin) to a response (stdout). This architecture worked for some time and became a common pattern,
- Performance: web applications are often written in languages that don't JIT and having a web server written in such a language would introduce extra overhead while milliseconds matter. Also, this lets us speed up static file serving,
- Security: Django's `runserver` is clearly described as potentially insecure, according to [this quote](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

  > DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay.

The last point seems to suggest that writing a production-ready HTTP server is too complex to fit within Django's goals, what kind of edge cases would need to be supported to get there?

Is any of the points actually valid, or am I missing the elephant in the room here?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Wsgi is the method by which Python applications talk to the web. Runserver *is* a wsgi server, it's just not a production level one.

Answer (score 2):

Because they don't want to get into the web server business, and I think that's a wise decision.

Creating, developing and most importantly maintaining a web server is not a trivial thing.  They couldn't simply write it once and then it's done (in fact, that's pretty much what they did and it's `runserver`).

Rather than re-invent the wheel, they've chosen to leave it to those who do it best.  They're not likely to match the stability and functionality of a proper web server by doing it as a side-project to support running Django applications.  They're better spending their time making Django better.

It's also consistent with the UNIX philosophy, but that's not necessary to get into here.